# Finding path with best distance/cost ratio from a node in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs

We have a weighted graph, where each node is a city. And the edges between the nodes are a pair of floating-point values (distance and cost of travel).

Given a node/city, describe an algorithm that can find the path with the largest distance/cost ratio from said node/city. Note that the path can traverse multiple nodes.

I need help with this (for both directed and undirected graphs). I stumbled across this question in a lecture note from my university (I graduated but am self-studying), and have no idea how to solve this.

There is no limitation on how to store the graphs, though I only know of adjacency matrix and adjacency list.

Comment: Are paths required to be simple? What's the cost of a path, is it just the sum of the costs of its edges?

Comment: This is asking for the path with maximum weighted average edge weight. If paths must be simple, this is NP-hard by reduction from Hamiltonian Path: Set all edges to have distance and cost 1, and add 2 extra vertices $s$ and $t$ that each have edges having distance 0 and cost 1 to every other vertex. Iff there is a HP, then there is an $st$ path with ratio $\frac{n-1}{n+1}$. (Notice that the average of 2 paths is in between their own averages, and the path from $s$ starts out at 0, so any edge with average 1 will be added if possible.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: this is exactly why I was asking if the path must be simple!

Comment: Hi @Steven, the question itself is constrained to simple graphs, but I'm curious about both simple and not simple graphs.

Comment: @zemageht, it is clear that the graph is simple. But is the sough path also required to be simple (you can have non-simple paths in simple graphs)?